# How to compute the inverse of an operation in Q#?

Tags: programming, q#

I want to implement amplitude amplification using Q#. I have the operation $A$
 that prepares my initial state and I need to compute $ A^{-1} $ to implement the algorithm.

Is there an easy way to do that in Q# (a keyword or operation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As given in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/techniques/operations-and-functions?view=qsharp-preview), if your operation is unitary, you can add the statement `adjoint auto;` within the operation after the body block. This will generate the adjoint (which is the inverse for unitary).

Then, to use the inverse call `Adjoint A(parameters)`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that the adjoint is also the inverse for unitary matrices.

Answer (score 5):

In the case that your operation can be represented by a unitary operator $U$ (this is typically the case if your operation doesn't use any measurements), you can indicate that by adding `is Adj` to your operation's signature, letting the Q# compiler know that your operation is *adjointable*:

```
open Microsoft.Quantum.Math as Math;

/// # Summary
/// Prepares a qubit in a state representing a classical probability
/// distribution {p, 1 - p}.
/// # Description
/// Given a qubit in the |0⟩, prepares √p |0⟩ + √(1 - p) |1⟩
/// for a given probability p.
operation PrepareDistribution(probability : Double, target : Qubit) : Unit
is Adj {
    let rotationAngle = 2.0 * Math.ArcCos(Math.Sqrt(1.0 - probability));
    Ry(rotationAngle, target);
}
```

You can then call `Adjoint PrepareDistribution` to "undo" the `PrepareDistribution` operation. The `Adjoint` keyword is an example of a Q# *functor*, and tells Q# that you want the inverse operation. In this case, the Q# compiler will apply `Ry(-rotationAngle, target)`.

For more information:

- [Functors](https://docs.microsoft.com/quantum/language/type-model#functors)
- [*Learn Quantum Computing with Python and Q#*](https://www.manning.com/books/learn-quantum-computing-with-python-and-q-sharp?a_aid=learn-qc-granade) (chapter 6 covers the example above, future chapters will talk more about functors)